# Let X and Y be random variables that $X,: \Omega \rightarrow R$ let $g$ be a measurable function that $Y=g(X)$, show $\sigma (Y) \subseteq \sigma (X)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am able to show $\sigma (Y) \subseteq \sigma (X)$ but I am also interested to show either $$\sigma (X) \subseteq \sigma (Y) \tag1$$ or $$\sigma (X) \nsubseteq \sigma (Y) \tag2$$

At the moment, I am not able to confidently and formally show which one is correct or incorrect.

What I started with is that since X and Y are both r.v. (which are measurable),  for any $A_i \in \sigma(x)$ and by the defined function $Y=g(X)$, $g(X(A_i)) = Y(A_i) = B_i : B_i \in B(R)$, which makes me think that (2) is correct. As for example,(for $i \neq j$), there can be $Y(A_i) = Y(A_j) = B_i$ for $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ and $X(A_i) = B_i$ and $X(A_j) = B_j$ where $B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$. Hence $\sigma(X)$ will be 'finer' than $\sigma(Y)$ and thus (2) is correct and we can conclusively say $\sigma (Y) \subseteq \sigma (X)$

I am not entirely sure I am correct and need some help with a more formal proof

Comment: Take $g=0$. You will see that the first one is false . Take $g$ to be identity and $Y=X$ to see that the secodn one is also false.

Comment: As a side note, in fact the following equivalence holds: If $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ are random variables, then $Y = g(X)$ for some measurable $g$ if and only if $\sigma(Y) \subseteq \sigma(X)$.